# pagination and search form issue

Tags: php, html

I have very basic pagination script and search form with ~4 fields, and `action="get"` now my problem is that, when i submit my form, i get url like this:

```
user/people/1/?search=true&country=uk&age=20&online=true ... and so on
```

so after i submit form everything is just fine, but when i go to page `2` my url changes to:

```
 user/people/2
```

so my search parameters disappears, this is how i render my links

```
 href="user/people/<?=$next?>"
```

So my question is what is the best way to keep my paramenters, because now i can only think of `for` loop and build my link by merging all `$_GET` values, should i do it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append `$_SERVER[ 'QUERY_STRING' ]` (make sure to `htmlspecialchars()` it first).

```
href="user/people/<?php echo htmlspecialchars( "{$next}?{$_SERVER[ 'QUERY_STRING' ]}" ); ?>"
```

By the way, the PHP short tags `<?= ?>` are not portable, so you should consider not using those, and using `<?php echo ?>` instead.

Update:

@Wrikken raises a couple of good points in their answer:

1) passing `ENT_QUOTES` as the second argument to `htmlspecialchars()` *would* be important if single-quoting the attribute value (or to cover it being changed to being single-quoted in the future).  This is easy to forget, for me anyway, since I almost always double-quote attribute values.  It's unfortunate that it further bloats a call that's already bloated by a long function name.

2) If you're just passing through the query string as-is, then I'd certainly prefer using `$_SERVER[ 'QUERY_STRING' ]` instead of `http_build_query( $_GET )`.  If, however, you need to change some of the query params, `http_build_query()` would be the ticket.  You can see an example of that in my [PHP faceted browser](https://github.com/jmm/Pure-PHP-Faceted-Browser/blob/public/resources/faceted_browser/faceted_browser.php).

Answer (score 1):

Either:

```
...ople/?<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], ENT_QUOTES);?>"
```

Or:

```
...ople/?<?php echo htmlspecialchars(http_build_query($_GET), ENT_QUOTES);?>"
```

Or:

```
...ople/?<?php echo htmlspecialchars(http_build_query($some_custom_array), ENT_QUOTES);?>"
```